# Why is datepicker beforeShowDay not acting as expected

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui-datepicker

I'm having trouble with a datepicker that I have created.  I am using a very similar datepicker on the same page with no issue at all.  The date picker shows with no selectable days, even though when I debug the 'limitToOneYear' function, it is returning true for some days. Am I missing something simple and obvious?

```
    function limitToOneYear(date) {
        var thisdate = Date.parse(date);
        var now = new Date();
        var today = Date.parse(new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate()));
        var maxDate = Date.parse(new Date((now.getFullYear() + 1), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()));
        return (thisdate >= today && thisdate < maxDate);
    }

    $(".expirationDate").datepicker({
        showOn: 'both',
        buttonImage: '/images/datepicker/button.gif',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        beforeShowDay: limitToOneYear
    });
```

Comment: Why are you creating a `Date` instance just to pass to `Date.parse()` to create a new `Date` instance? That just strikes me as unnecessary and convoluted, unless there's something important I'm missing.

Comment: new date get's the current date unless you pass stuff to it, date parse gets a representative integer. So what it does is get an integer representative of today's date (midnight). There may be an easier way to compare dates but I'm currently unaware of it

Comment: Aha, the fact that it returns an integer representation, rather than a Date object, is what I was missing. Thanks!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Should you not be returning an array from your limitToOneYear function as per the DatePicker API for [beforeShowDay](http://docs.jquery.com/UI/Datepicker#event-beforeShowDay)

So your limitToOneYear function should be something like this

```
function limitToOneYear(date) {         
    var thisdate = Date.parse(date);         
    var now = new Date();         
    var today = Date.parse(new Date(now.getFullYear(),now.getMonth(),now.getDate()));         
    var maxDate = Date.parse(new Date((now.getFullYear() + 1), now.getMonth(), now.getDate()));         
    return [(thisdate >= today && thisdate < maxDate), '']; 
}
```

Comment: Yes, yes I should, I don't know how I missed that, thank you!

Answer (score 1):

I found A solution so I'm posting it, I would still like to understand why my previous solution isn't working so I will select a different answer if it presents itself, but I ended up taking advantage of the minDate maxDate properties of datepicker:

```
    var now = new Date();
    var endDate = now;
    endDate = new Date((now.getFullYear() + 1), now.getMonth(), now.getDate());
    $(".expirationDate").datepicker({
        showOn: 'both',
        buttonImage: '/images/datepicker/button.gif',
        buttonImageOnly: true,
        minDate : now, 
        maxDate: endDate
    });
```